# How to return desable account attribute using GraphAPI

Tags: groovy, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using MS Graph APi to collect information about a user in order to know if user is desactivated or not

For that when testing it with POSTMAN as below the accoutnÊnabled parameter is returning ok

[image]

Then I try to call the same API using groovy script as below :

```
public String getUserStatus(String AuthToken,String userId){

    String _enable
    def http = new HTTPBuilder(graph_base_user_url + "4f06f2bf-8943-4d21-9ef7-e8aeba07832f" + "?")

        http.request(GET) {

            requestContentType = ContentType.JSON
            query:['$select': 'accountEnabled']

            headers.'Authorization' = "Bearer " + AuthToken    

            response.success = { resp, json ->
                 _enable=json["accountEnabled"].toString()
            }

            // user ID not found : error 404
            response.'404' = { resp ->       
                _enable = 'Not Found'
            }

        }
        _enable
    }
```

By doing so the json return string is returning the whole user object information instead of only the accountEnabled attribute as specified by the filter.

Any reason why the select query does not work ?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `query:['\$select': 'accountEnabled']` instead should fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, I had to use the following syntax :

uri.query=[$select:"accountEnabled"]

regards
serge